# Image manipulation filter needed: unobtrusively hide an area by blurring or smudging?

Tags: images, editing, plugins, adobe-photoshop, gimp

I would like to hide an empty area of a panorama stitched with hugin (using the GIMP). Hide in the sense of blending it in unobtrusively. I.e. fill the area with the average color of the surroundings and blur it. Or manually smudge the surroundings into the empty area.

Is there a filter/plug-in that automatically smudges/blurs the edges into the area?

Not looking for seam carving. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen such an Plugin so far...I think the easiest way would be by doing this by hand. Draw raw/sketchy lines with the Paint-Tool according to the surrounding images, and after that blur or pixelize the area.

Answer (score 0):

Blur your image parts before stiching with hugin.

Hugin can use enblend so why do you mess with gimp stiching?